# How to import a script for my project ? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm a project and that project have a "bootstrap" own, and i would want to import it for my render.

I created an archive HTML with the scripts:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script> //1.www.s81c.com/common/v18/css/www.css</script>
        <script> //1.www.s81c.com/common/stats/ida_stats.js</script>
        <script> //1.www.s81c.com/common/v18/js/www.js</script>
    </head>
</html>
```

and imported in my `App.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
***import './V18.html'***;


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 class="nameOfClassImported" className="App-title">BEM VINDX</h1>
        </header>
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

but given that error:

```
> Failed to compile.
./src/V18.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <html>
|     <head>
|         <script> //1.www.s81c.com/common/v18/css/www.css</script>
```

**Resume:**
I want to import scripts for i to use in my `App.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tag for the .css file should be `<link>`.

There are multiple ways to import external scripts.  One way that does work is to move these scripts to the `<head>` of your `public/index.html`.

```
/// public/index.html ///
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//1.www.s81c.com/common/stats/ida_stats.js"></script>
    <link href="//1.www.s81c.com/common/v18/css/www.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//1.www.s81c.com/common/v18/js/www.js"></script>
/// rest of public/index.html ///
```

Those scripts will be downloaded when your page loads and you can access the variables in those scripts on the `window` object.  After linking to these from your `public/index.html`, restart your React app, then open the console with F12 or Command-Option-i and type `window` into the console.  There you will see all the global functions that are available from within your React app including `window.IBMCore`, `window.Modernizr`, etc

Comment: THANKS BROTHER, I LOVE YOU <3

Comment: Did this fix your issue?  If it did, making it the accepted answer would make my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='..//1.www.s81c.com/common/stats/ida_stats.js'></script>
```

and for following can you try a regular `<link />` instead of `<script>`

Comment: Thank you for to answer but the problem continue.. :(

Comment: is it same error? Can you show me what you put down for script and link tags?

Answer (score 0):

import those in index.html path is `public.index.html`. Because your app put in one of div of same html page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Read this how webpack work.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

else other way is save file and import at **App.js**

```
import './App.scss';
```