# Converting a dynamic HTML page to React/JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

As a simple example, suppose I had these two files:

#### example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Button example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ButtonHandler.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body" onload="init()">
    <button onclick=buttonHandler.writeToConsole()>Button</button>
    <script>

        function init() {
            buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### ButtonHandler.js

```
function ButtonHandler() {

};

ButtonHandler.prototype.writeToConsole = function () {
    console.log('Writing');
}
```

This simply prints to the console whenever the button is clicked.

Ignore that the ButtonHandler's constructor is empty, and that I could just easily call 'console.log' in the onclick directly. This is a simplified version of an issue I'm having, with several classes.

My question is, how would I go about translating this to React/JSX, **ideally without modifying the Javascript files** (in this case, just ButtonHandler.js). Ideally this means no exporting/importing, I'd like to do it how the HTML file does it - it just links to the script in the <\head>.

The closest I have is something like this:

#### convert.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';   

export default class Entry extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <title>Button example</title>
                <button onclick="buttonHandler.writeToConsole()">Button</button>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

But I get the error that ButtonHandler is undefined. I followed this [stackexchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49714329/8686793) and placed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[rest of path...]/ButtonHandler.js"></script>
```

in the public/index head, and I added the 'window.ButtonHandler' in componentDidMount(), but I still get the error that it's undefined.

Am I doing something wrong, and if not, what other approach can I take?

edit: When I put ButtonHandler.js in the public folder with index, and I console log the window, I see it appear as a function of window, like the stackexchange answer describes. This doesn't happen when I have it in another folder, though. Same error however.

edit 2: Seems the only solution is to put ButtonHandler.js in the public folder and then call it in the constructor like the selected answer says. Then add a

`<button onClick={() => this.buttonHandler.writeToConsole()}>Button</button>`

to call it.

Comment: Is ButtonHandler.js file in your public folder?

Comment: No, it exists in the same folder as example.html.

But even putting it in the public folder gives the same error.

Comment: Are you using create react app by chance?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: Actually there does seem to be a difference. When I have ButtonHandler.js in the public folder, and I console log the window, I see it appear as a function of window, like the stackexchange answer describes. This is not the case when it isn't in the public folder though. I get the same error regardless, however.

Comment: You need to define `ButtonHandler` in the component that it's used in. See my answer for an example of doing that by `import`ing the js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In create react app, you should be able to add any js files to your public folder for use in your project. You just need to reference the files in your script like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/ButtonHandler.js"></script>
```

That will make sure that it looks in the public folder when building.

The only problem with that is that the files won't be minified in the bundle.

**Edit**

You will have to reference the global variable inside your component as well.

```
/* global ButtonHandler */

import * as React from 'react';   

export default class Entry extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  this.buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <title>Button example</title>
            <button onclick={this.buttonHandler.writeToConsole}>Button</button>
        </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is any different than what I already did

Comment: Edited. I think you need to reference the global namespace at the top of your component?

Comment: Can you go slightly more indepth? I think maybe your code got cut short. I searched up how to declare a global variable in React and it's not exactly straightforward.

Comment: Well I can access the prototype like this:

"window.ButtonHandler.prototype.writeToConsole".

Not sure how to create the buttonHandler though, using the 'new' keyword

Comment: Try instantiating it in the constructor instead. Edited above. That was the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there any way to get it working when the ButtonHandler.js file is not in the public folder? When I put it outside that folder and set the path it doesn't work. I'd rather not have to copy/paste every file I need into public.

Comment: From my experience, I've usually exported ES6 classes, imported them into the components I needed the methods in, and instantiated a new instance in the constructor of said component. I realize that you are trying to avoid that. I'm not sure if there's an easier workaround though.

Comment: Yeah I've decided to import/export what I need. It's just that I'm not sure how to translate an HTML's body onload() function, since that's called after the HTML has been loaded. If I put the Javascript in the component's constructor, it won't work, since it expects some div elements from the HTML body that hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: If you instantiate the class in the constructor and then call those methods in `componentDidMount`,  does it work? `componentDidMount` runs after the render function, which contains your "html" so I would think that might solve the problem.

Comment: I've figured out a solution. You can just simply put the class in componentDidMount() and instantiate them with "this" like you do in the constructor. I don't know why I didn't think of this earlier

Comment: Those little things do slip by. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to `import` that `ButtonHandler` js code. If it's not something you've written yourself, the easiest thing to do would be to see if it already exists as a React package. If it's your own file, then you'll want to export the functions in ButtonHandler.js, `import ButtonHandler` in your React component, then you'll have access to them in the component.

**ButtonHandler.js**

```
export function writeToConsole() {
  console.log('Writing');
}
```

**convert.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { writeToConsole } from './ButtonHandler';

export default class Entry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <title>Button example</title>
        <button onclick={this.writeToConsole}>Button</button>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that I need to import the entire ButtonHandler "class", not just a function, and I don't know if that's even possible. Everything I try gives me the same error - that it's undefined.